# How to locate TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: android, react-native

I upgraded my react-native application to 0.61.5 and some of my rn library, then I got ~0.3% of my user raised this exception:
TransactionTooLargeException

Trying to find which library causing this error without any success.
Because logcat doesn't show the error source in stacktrace
After reading a bunch of SO articles, no solution comes to me.

My question is:

**How can I know which library produces that error?**

---- update ----

I found the library [toolargetool](https://github.com/guardian/toolargetool) might be helpful in locating this error.

Comment: It will show you which item is using large amount of data. Are you using intents to transfer data between activities?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 libraries using Intent to transfer data, but the data size is very tiny (plain text), I'm sure.

Comment: Are you passing images??

Comment: No, I just passed some plain text. I'm thinking about some other libraries so I need a way to locate this error source.